What are “panic blood moons”?
I hear the term "panic blood moon" thrown around occasionally, in regards to Breath of the Wild or Tears of the Kingdom.
What are they though? I don’t think the term comes up in either game.

It's a forced Blood moon that happens when the game needs to free some memory. And no, it's never mentioned in-game because it's an unusual mechanic.
As stated in Zelda wiki:

In situations where the game is running out of memory or assets are not loading correctly, a "Panic" Blood Moon will be triggered, even during daytime. When this occurs, the game does a harder reset of the game state, attempting to clear memory and go to a known, possibly less buggy state, in order to prevent a crash or game-breaking glitch.
This extended reset usually causes the Blood Moon cutscene to be unskippable, and the loading screen afterwards to take tens of seconds.

